# Retain string after being returned from multiple hooked events in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, events

I wasn't sure how to google for this one, So it may be a dumb question, but I'm gonna ask it anyway.

I have an event that wants the delegates to return a string.

```
public delegate string IncomingMessageHook(SpecialClasses.IncomingMessageData msg);
public event IncomingMessageHook InComingMessage;
```

When multiple delegate methods are hooked to the event, how do I prevent one method from overriding the output of the other?
I only want the output of the method that returns a string, and not a NULL value. 
Is there a way to achieve this or is this outright impossible?
Thanks!

**Edit:**
An example situation would be like this:

```
        public string NewMessage(string[] _message, System.Net.IPEndPoint RemoteIP)
        {

            if (InComingMessage != null)
            {
                string toreturn = InComingMessage(new SpecialClasses.IncomingMessageData(_message, RemoteIP));
                return toreturn;
            }
            else return null;
        }
//this calls the event and retrieves a string from it, then returns that.


    static string Return_Null(OnyLib.SpecialClasses.IncomingMessageData msg)
    {
        return null;
    }
//This hooked method returns null.


    static string Return_Something(OnyLib.SpecialClasses.IncomingMessageData msg)
    {
        return "Something!";
    }
//this hooked method returns "Something!"
```

With the above code, how do I make sure that If I call NewMessage() It'll return "Something!" and not NULL?

Comment: What do you mean by "only want the output of"? You can't control what public event handlers will return. Can you show the code where you are using this handler?

Comment: I meant that there are multiple methods hooked to the event which all have to return something (since the delegate demands it), but they all return NULL except ONE, and I want the string that ONE method returns. I'll whip up some code to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without passing judgement on your design. It is possible to accomplish this.
You need to iterate over the subcribers to the InComingMessage event and check the return value from each delegate's invocation. The following code demonstrates this.

```
    public delegate string IncomingMessageHook(int id);
    public event IncomingMessageHook InComingMessage;
    private string OnInComingMessage(int id)
    {
        IncomingMessageHook handler = null;
        Delegate[] targets = null;
        string result;

        handler = InComingMessage;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            targets = handler.GetInvocationList();
            foreach (Delegate target in targets)
            {
                try
                {
                    handler = (IncomingMessageHook)target;
                    result = handler.Invoke(id);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
   }
```

Comment: Ohey! I was hoping there was something like that, well I already have it working now, using a list that gets passed on, but I'll mark this is as answer since it comes closer to the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this makes no sense, to return anything other than void from an event handler, for exactly the reason highlighted by your question. You should redesign your model. the delegate should return void and there should be some other mechanism for processing the string that results from handling the message. perhaps simply a method on the class that raises the event.

Comment: Damnit, I knew this was going to come out :P Oh well, I'll just set some string in some instance of a class. I'll leave this up just a bit longer just in case, but I'll mark it as answer in ~1 hour. Thanks for clarifying.